# How to add many axis spines one below the other

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to add the axes spines (different parameter one below other as shown in the plot below).
I am using axes twiny which is making me plot one at the top and the other at the bottom.
I am not able to arrange the parameter one below the other (the below code is giving altitude in the above axis,sza (above), lat(below)).

any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

figure:

[image: Refrence figure of the requirement]

Here is my code: I have shown the steps I have followed

```
ax1 = plt.axes()
ax1.plot(time,data)    # Time 


ax2=ax1.twiny()
ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
ax2.set_xticks(aaa)
ax2.set_xticklabels(alst,color='red',fontsize=12)   # second parameter Altitude
ax2.spines['bottom'].set_position(('outward', 20))

ax3=ax1.twiny()
ax3.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
ax3.set_xticks(aaa)
ax3.set_xticklabels(latt,color='blue',fontsize=12) # latitude
ax3.spines['bottom'].set_position(('outward', 20))

ax4=ax1.twiny()
ax4.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
ax4.set_xticks(aaa)
ax4.set_xticklabels(sza,color='blue',fontsize=12) #sza
ax4.spines['bottom'].set_position(('outward', 20))

# similarly I need to add Longitude,LT.
```

Comment: Your image shows a table beneath a graph. [Is this what you try to achieve](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/table_demo.html)?

Comment: Yes...I am looking for the parameters to display one below another

Comment: So, have you tried to adapt the table demo? This problem seems not to be related to the creation of secondary axes.